# Expo React Native Date Picker with just month and year

Tags: react-native, npm, datepicker, expo

I am trying to create a date picker with just month and year spinner - like in LinkedIn job experiences.

Is there an expo managed workflow react native npm package that could support this kind of configuration and if not what is the quickest way I could implement it on my own?

Answer (score 3):

there's no way with the expo date picker, that is the community date picker, the same as react native CLI recommends.

But you can use this npm library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-month-year-picker

There's other way, you can create your own picker here:

https://github.com/TronNatthakorn/react-native-wheel-pick

UPDATE:

I have good news, I found this on GitHub https://gist.github.com/falcon11/a3ffb6efcb96d838ffa027daf96cca36#file-yearmonthpicker-js

There's an issue with the picker, so you have to install the picker community package:

https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker

If you have any issues I'ill be happy to help you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2uik.png)

Comment: Thanks for submitting your answer. Can you please provide a **minimal** code example (e.g. a basic usage example of the linked components) just so it doesn't get flagged as a [link only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: These libraries are also not supported in expo.

Comment: Hi Boyan, you're right there's no compatibility with expo, I'm sorry. The only way is to detach your project.